# I want to programme google sheets to reset a check box and upload number of check boxes ticked to a different sheet and post with the date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a maintenance google sheet which has check boxes next to the assigned task. I have set up a code that refreshes the boxes daily, but I want to know the number of check boxes ticked and to post it to a different sheet with the date automatically. Could anyone help with the automatic upload part?

I have already attempted the code to untick the check boxes daily, but do not know how to upload number of ticked check boxes to a different sheet.

```
function getDataDaily(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily');
  sheet.getRange('L3:L119').setValue('Incomplete')

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Results for Daily')


}
```

The code has unticked the check boxes when I run it. However I am completely lost with uploading the number.

Comment: Are your check boxes located in column L?

Comment: Yeah they are, the total count is located on column L 120

Answer (score 0):

### Add the following code into your function before unticking the checkboxes:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily');
  var number= sheet.getRange('L120').getValue();
  var timeStamp=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
  var uploadSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById("MYSPREADSHEETID").getSheetByName('MYSHEETNAME');
  var lastRow=uploadSheet.getLastRow();
  var timeStampRange=uploadSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1);
  var numberRange=uploadSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2);
  timeStampRange.setValue(timeStamp);
  numberRange.setValue(number);
```

This code will retrieve the number in `L120` and append it together with the current timestamp into the spreadsheet and sheet of your choice to the first free row in this sheet.

As for unchecking the tickboxes, you can do it with

```
 sheet.getRange('L3:L119').uncheck();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For it to be automated, does the project trigger handle that? Thank you again

Comment: Please have a look at the different available triggers and their restrictions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/  Which kind of action should trigger the script to run?

Comment: I have been looking at a time-based action, does that mean the code will run in between the times selected or at the end?

Comment: It means that it will run with a certain frequency, e.g. every hour or every ten minutes.